# Unresolved <iostream> in Eclipse, Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, gcc, eclipse-cdt

Yes, it's **this** question again...

Somehow, I cannot get this issue resolved.  Believe it or not, I have experience with Eclipse but only for Java development.  I have programmed in C++ using vi but not with Eclipse.

I have installed:

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Eclipse 3.7.2
- GCC 4.6.3
- Eclipse CDT 8.0.2

I created an empty Makefile project and selected the Linux GNU Toolchain:

[image: empty Makefile project]

I get the standard `Unresolved inclusion <iostream>` error, and I have some references to various "include" directories in the project:

[image: <code>Unresolved inclusion <iostream></code> error]

I did notice that, while my "Paths and Symbols" setting for GNU C contains various paths, the same setting for GNU C++ is empty:

[image: GNU C Paths and Symbols]

[image: GNU C++ Paths and Symbols]

Also, I have the "GNU Elf Parser" under my C/C++ build settings:

[image]

---

### **What am I doing wrong here?**

Cheers

---

**Edit:**

Here's an updated photo of my a project's build path that is working correctly:
[image: Updated build path]

Comment: You have empty GNU C++ Paths, while it should contain similar includes as GNU C and 3 more additional paths.

Comment: @Benjamin Do you happen to know what are the additional 3 paths that I am missing?

Comment: I have: /usr/include/c++/4.6, /usr/include/c++/4.6/backward, /usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64....

Comment: @Benjamin ah, I think I can assume that the default installation of Ubuntu 12.04 comes with C libraries but not C++.  I will try to install the appropriate C++ libraries now.

Comment: install built-essential in ubuntu, it should work, or simply find as I wrote below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that Eclipse simply cannot import a proper header. C++ iostream header in Ubuntu can be found:

> $: sudo find / -name iostream
>
> ```
> /home/beniamin/QtSDK/Madde/toolchains/arm-2009q3-67-arm-none-linux-gnueabi-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/arm-2009q3-67/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.4.1/iostream
> /home/beniamin/QtSDK/Madde/sysroots/harmattan_sysroot_10.2011.34-1_slim/usr/include/c++/4.4/iostream
> /usr/share/gccxml-0.9/GCC/2.95/iostream
> /usr/include/c++/4.6/iostream
> /usr/include/boost/tr1/tr1/iostream
> ```

So basically, I suppose the one you are looking for is `/usr/include/c++/4.6/iostream`, so you should in some place include this directory.

Edit: You should also have installed g++, or simply install build-essential package, which is obligatory for building debian packages. Nevertheless, g++ should have been included in your Ubuntu installation anyway.

Comment: Yep!  I was lacking the build-essential installation.  Odd that the default installation of Ubuntu 12.04 did not include this, but regardless, `sudo apt-get install build-essential` fixed this.  Thanks!

Comment: It got fixed after I included the iostream path in the include directories. 
However, though it now builds the project correctly, it still shows a question mark symbol next to the includes "Unresolved inclusion". Why is it still there? Any possible explanation ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I have found that using

```
$: sudo find / -name iostream
```

and adding the includes file in the includes path and then it success.