# Std Library on Eclipse Ubuntu

Tags: c++, eclipse, std

I have stack eclipse on Ubuntu to develop a c++ project.
My problem is when I want to develop c++ code with Eclipse, Eclipse does not recognize my C++ code for example;

```
using namespace std;
cin
cout
```

I says "std" could not be resolved.

I have researched on internet but I cannot solve problem. What should I do to solve my problem?

Note: My eclipse version is Version: 3.8.0
Operating System Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Did you maybe forget to put `#include <iostream>` in your code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335420/unresolved-iostream-in-eclipse-ubuntu