# How to solve Unresolved inclusion: <iostream> in eclipse?

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, helios

I built a simple program in eclipse:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "TEST" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It worked in Visual Studio and CodeBlocks, but eclipse is acting weird. it says:

`Unresolved inclusion: <iostream>`

I read here:
[C++ - Unresolved inclusion: <iostream>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373788/c-unresolved-inclusion-iostream)

and here: [Unresolved <iostream> in Eclipse, Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12335420/unresolved-iostream-in-eclipse-ubuntu)

and neither of them worked.

Here are screenshots of `project properties`:

[image: build_settings]
[image: general]

**edit:**

I downloaded [MinGW](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get-setup.exe/download) and now i have this under `Settings`:

[image: Updated_Settings]

How should i proceed?
Maybe now i don't need `#include <iostream>` because it's now included in the project?

[image: include]

I found `iostream` under `Includes`.

So i tried deleting `#include <iostream>`, but when i try to run the program i get:
`Launch Failed. Binary not found.` error:

[image: launch_failed]

Thanks

**edit:**

Seems like if i compile in some other program (say CodeBlocks) and create the `exe` file, then `eclipse` can run it. But it can't build its own `exe`.

Why?

Comment: So did you actually do the `find` command suggested in your second link?

Comment: i thought that's only for ubunto?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve "Unresolved inclusion: <iostream>" in a C++ file in Eclipse CDT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373788/how-to-solve-unresolved-inclusion-iostream-in-a-c-file-in-eclipse-cdt)

Answer (score 1):

This answer did not help me either. My issue was solved with the following steps:

You might try changing your source files from *.c to *.cpp. This will provoke gcc to think of the files as C++ and search the proper paths. Might need to make small modifications to the Makefile as well, like on the OBJ: line. Instead of:

OBJS = YourFile.o

try

OBJS = YourFile.cpp

Answer (score 0):

I've searched for a few hours and tried a lot solutions.

Envirment: windows, Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers

Version: Kepler Service Release 2

CDT: 8.3.0

Following steps works for me:

1. make sure the envirement is clear. => **I suggest delete the eclipse and unzip it again from your orginal download.**
2. make sure the workspace is clear. => **Delete .metadata folder in your workspace folder.**
3. use valid MinGW. => the one using download tool is slow and I'm not sure which one to select. I suggest **download MinGWStudio** from http://vaultec.mbnet.fi/mingwstudio.php
   This is a IDE tool like eclipse contains a downloaded unzip MinGW. Make sure you download the one plus MinGW compiler which is about 20M. You can use this studio if you want or copy the MinGW folder to **C:/** if you still prefer eclipse. **Copy /MinGW inside /MinGWStudio to C:/**.
4. close your eclipse and reopen it, **create a new project**, you should able to see MinGW section for new project option, and it will auto map g++, gcc and include files under C:/MinGW folder. Just make sure you copy MinGW folder from MinGWStudio to the root of C:/.

You will able to see your include after these steps.

[includes_screen_cast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOCs3.png)

Answer (score -2):

right click your project click properties goto C/C++ Build > settings click on Misc. under GCC C++ Compiler and the other flags code should have this after it -std=c++11 then go to Misc. under GCC C Compiler and add this to the other flags code -std=gnu11 apply save your project build your project and it should work

Comment: There is no such thing as "misc".